# How to write this MySQL query using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working with a Rails 5 project and have a SQL query that looks like the following:

```
SELECT foo1.* 
 FROM foos foo1 
 WHERE foo1.created_at = 
   ( SELECT MIN(foo2.created_at) FROM foos foo2 WHERE foo2.user_id = foo1.user_id );
```

The model here is named `Foo` and the underlying table is named `foos`. I want to write a method that'll basically give me one record per user_id with the earliest created_at timestamp which the SQL query above will solve. I just want to write it using ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial query you have doesn't necessarily give you one record per `user_id`.

Here's an example:

```
# created_at1 < created_at2
foo1 = Foo.create!(user_id: 1, created_at: created_at1)
foo2 = Foo.create!(user_id: 1, created_at: created_at2)
foo3 = Foo.create!(user_id: 2, created_at: created_at2)
```

Your query will select the minimum `created_at` for each `user_id`, so it will get `created_at1` from `foo1` and `created_at2` from `foo3`. But since `foo2` and `foo3` share the same `created_at`, all three records will be returned.

A better way to select the records would be (For Postgres):

`Foo.select('DISTINCT ON ("user_id") *').order(:user_id, created_at: :asc)`